# What am I missing to fix my SSL Error related to a finance API?

Tags: python, api, ssl

I cannot find a solution when reading through other posts on SOF. Every demo and youtube is able to run a different scenario than the code listed below and get an output without an error.

I've found many solutions for other codes I've written on SOF, but after an entire weekend looking for something, I've decided to make a post about it.

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
import requests

url = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query"

querystring = {"symbol":"TSLA","function":"GLOBAL_QUOTE"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "4f4624778bmsh7bd5b2d7f4e011ap154d47jsn07dedf36b055"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

**Parts of the error:**

```
Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

then further into it:

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com', port=443): Max retries 
exceeded with url: /query?symbol=TSLA&function=GLOBAL_QUOTE (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad 
handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify 
failed')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

then at the very end is the following:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded 
with url: /query?symbol=TSLA&function=GLOBAL_QUOTE (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: 
Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `verify=False` as get parameter

```
import requests

url = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query"

querystring = {"symbol":"TSLA","function":"GLOBAL_QUOTE"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "4f4624778bmsh7bd5b2d7f4e011ap154d47jsn07dedf36b055"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

Output:

```
<Response [200]>
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "TSLA",
        "02. open": "1515.0000",
        "03. high": "1517.0500",
        "04. low": "1420.9800",
        "05. price": "1430.7600",
        "06. volume": "12246960",
        "07. latest trading day": "2020-07-31",
        "08. previous close": "1487.4900",
        "09. change": "-56.7300",
        "10. change percent": "-3.8138%"
    }
}
```

Comment: I read that verify false isn't safe, it worked for me, but I'm hesitant as this is on my work laptop. Since I'll be running this on my own on a schedule, is there anything to worry about since it's not going to be in any kind of app?

Comment: If you are worried then you will need to download the SSL certificates

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question but where would I download this from? I’m assuming alpha vantage. What would that pip/import be to obtain them?

Comment: No, you will have to download from browser https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file